# how to make httpPost call with json encoded body?

Tags: android, http-post

i am using following code to make an httpPost call but it is returning me 400 bad request
when i try to give following parameters in "simple rest client" in chrome extension it works fine any one guide me what mistake am i doing here?

Simple rest Client I entered the following:

URL: http://jon2012.com/api/register
Method: POST
Headers: No headers, as they are not required
Data: { "email": "test@example.com", "first_name":"Name" }[image]

Android Code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try{
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            json.put("email", email);
            json.put("first_name", name);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "JSON: " + json.toString());  
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            post.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(post);
            /*Checking response */
            /*if(response!=null){
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
*/
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
           // createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
        }
```

any help would be appriciated

Comment: Is your json data pattern is same as the service required?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was making a common mistake sequence of json object was wrong.
For example, I was sending it like
first_name, email, etc. where as the correct sequence was email, first_name.

My code:

```
boolean result = false;
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
String message;

HttpPost p = new HttpPost(url);
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
try {
    object.put("updates", updates);
    object.put("mobile", mobile);
    object.put("last_name", lastname);
    object.put("first_name", firstname);
    object.put("email", email);

} catch (Exception ex) {

}

try {
    message = object.toString();

    p.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
    p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(p);
    if (resp != null) {
        if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204)
            result = true;
    }

    Log.d("Status line", "" + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}

return result;
```

Comment: The order in which you add your params should make absolutely NO difference whatsoever. The web server receiving the params should NOT care what order the params are in only that the params are nested correctly and the keys are defined correctly

Comment: I'm not sure how this is the correct answer... and it's been voted up by four people.  The order of JSON params definitely doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code for calling rest services with Http POST and JSON:

(Note that I'm using AndroidHttpClient, which's basically a DefaultHttpClient with some preset attributes, and Google's GSON project for JSON marshalling)

Class for handling communication:

```
public class NetworkComm extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = "NetworkComm";

    private AndroidHttpClient hc;
    private HttpContext localContext;
    private TaskResponseListener listener;
    private int reqType;
    private String message;
    private String url;
    private Object extra;

    public NetworkComm(AndroidHttpClient hc, HttpContext localContext, TaskResponseListener listener, 
            int reqType, String message, String url, Object extra){
        super();

        this.hc = hc;
        this.localContext = localContext;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.reqType = reqType;
        this.message = message;
        this.url = url;
        this.extra = extra;
    }

    public AndroidHttpClient getHc() {
        return hc;
    }

    public void setHc(AndroidHttpClient hc) {
        this.hc = hc;
    }

    public HttpContext getLocalContext() {
        return localContext;
    }

    public void setLocalContext(HttpContext localContext) {
        this.localContext = localContext;
    }

    public void start(){
        this.execute(message);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Don't do anything here
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... req) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Message to send: "+req[0]);
        HttpPost p = new HttpPost(url);

        try{
            p.setEntity(new StringEntity(req[0], "UTF8"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        String response = "";
        try{
            HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(p, localContext);
            InputStream is = resp.getEntity().getContent();
            response = convertStreamToString(is);
            Log.d("Response", "Response is " + response);

            Log.d("Status line", ""+resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         // dont handle this yet
     }

     @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         Log.d("task", "task finished");
         listener.onTaskResponse(reqType, result, extra);
     }

     public interface TaskResponseListener{
         public void onTaskResponse(int type, String response, Object extra);
     }

     private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        if (is != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {        
            return "";
        }
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
        SomeContent content = new SomeContent("Stuff", 4);
        String message = g.toJson(content);

        NetworkComm task = new NetworkComm(hc, localContext, listener, 0, message, url, "");
        task.start();
```

Hope that this helps.

Comment: i want to send two parameters email and name could you please guide me where to use them ?

Comment: what is Gson? and what is Somecontent actually this is confusing part

Comment: SomeContent is some content :) A custom class that has the fields containing the data that you want to send. Gson is used to put it into json, google it up, it's quite handy and easier to use than the default json lib in the android sdk.

Comment: thanks for help i have summarized and implemented simple solution with the help of yours.