# How can I access neo4j running on ( any http or localhost) from android

Tags: android, neo4j

I am successfully implemented neo4j on both mac and java application but I cannot access the same from and android and the it crashes at dbpath.But it keeps crashing.How can I get it to work?

INstead of

```
graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH);
```

it is

```
 RestAPI graphDb = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
```

also tried

```
 GraphDatabaseService graphDb=new RestGraphDatabase(“http://localhost:7474/db/data”);
```

Entire Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils;

public class EmbeddedNeo4j {
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/home/User/Documents/neo4j/";
    String greeting;
    // START SNIPPET: vars
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    Node firstNode;
    Node secondNode;
    Relationship relationship;

    // END SNIPPET: vars

    // START SNIPPET: createReltype
    private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType {
        KNOWS
    }

    // END SNIPPET: createReltype

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EmbeddedNeo4j hello = new EmbeddedNeo4j();
        hello.createDb();
        hello.removeData();
        hello.shutDown();
    }

    void createDb() {
        clearDb();
        // START SNIPPET: startDb
        graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH);
        registerShutdownHook(graphDb);
        // END SNIPPET: startDb

        // START SNIPPET: transaction
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try {
            // Mutating operations go here
            // END SNIPPET: transaction
            // START SNIPPET: addData
            firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
            firstNode.setProperty("message", "Hello, ");
            secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
            secondNode.setProperty("message", "World!");

            relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo(secondNode,
                    RelTypes.KNOWS);
            relationship.setProperty("message", "brave Neo4j ");
            // END SNIPPET: addData

            // START SNIPPET: readData
            System.out.print(firstNode.getProperty("message"));
            System.out.print(relationship.getProperty("message"));
            System.out.print(secondNode.getProperty("message"));
            // END SNIPPET: readData

            greeting = ((String) firstNode.getProperty("message"))
                    + ((String) relationship.getProperty("message"))
                    + ((String) secondNode.getProperty("message"));

            // START SNIPPET: transaction
            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }
        // END SNIPPET: transaction
    }

    private void clearDb() {
        try {
            FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File(DB_PATH));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    void removeData() {
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try {
            // START SNIPPET: removingData
            // let's remove the data
            firstNode.getSingleRelationship(RelTypes.KNOWS, Direction.OUTGOING)
                    .delete();
            firstNode.delete();
            secondNode.delete();
            // END SNIPPET: removingData

            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }
    }

    void shutDown() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Shutting down database ...");
        // START SNIPPET: shutdownServer
        graphDb.shutdown();
        // END SNIPPET: shutdownServer
    }

    // START SNIPPET: shutdownHook
    private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        // Registers a shutdown hook for the Neo4j instance so that it
        // shuts down nicely when the VM exits (even if you "Ctrl-C" the
        // running example before it's completed)
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }
    // END SNIPPET: shutdownHook

}
```

Comment: do you want to run Neo4j on Android or do you want to access a Neo4j instance running on some server from an Android app?

Comment: I want access neo4j instance running on my mac (localhost:7474) from android .Basically an Http call .I dont want to install neo4j on my device.Thanks Stefan for looking into this query.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster on some server from android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EmbeddedGraphDatabase` can only be used if the DB and your client code should reside in the same JVM (therefore the word 'embedded').

If you want to remote access a Neo4j server the best ways today is either communicating with the [transactional Cypher endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) directly or using the [Neo4j JDBC driver](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc). Please note, in both cases you use Cypher to interact with the graph.

The library for [java rest bindings](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding) is originated in the days where the two mentioned approached where not yet in place - so java-rest-bindings will be deprecated in the future.

Comment: So how can I use http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html  ,I mean: If I want to return "MATCH (ee:Person) WHERE ee.name = "Emil" RETURN ee;" then How can I do the same in android.Here POST request will have key,value .So How or what I have to send to get the query above?? Thanks for your time .I really appreciate it.I am stuck here for a long time..Thanks again.

Comment: How do I pass parameter when sending POST request ?

Comment: So how should I proceed ?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533234/how-to-make-httppost-call-with-json-encoded-body

Comment: but how/where do I define the function for particular path ? Like http://jon2012.com/api/register  as mentioned in the example : api/register is located where ? .If I am using php then I can define the path but how to do the same for neo4j ?

Comment: instead of jon2012.com/api/register use http://myhostname.com:7474/db/data/transaction/commit

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work .I tried neo4j-jdbc https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc but I get class not found error.Can you please explain step by step implementation of  localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit  .Please.I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you throw more light on transactional Cypher endpoint  or an step by step tutorial?

Comment: Hi Stefan.I have a query .How can I loop through create/merge in rest call .I tried passing params/array but it working only for single value not for array.Please help me out.I would really appreciate  your  help.Thanks .Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716699/parameter-maps-cannot-be-used-in-merge-patterns  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714278/create-is-working-but-merge-in-neo4j-post-params-has-error

Comment: How can I loop through 100 numbers ? Should I call merge statement 100 times ?