# How to solve the HTTP 414 “Request URI too long” error in android / base64 image?

Tags: android, http

I am trying to pull an base64 encoded image from my app to database(which is in my server), but I get this error.

```
the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Long)
```

I know that for URLs, shortening them fixes the error but I can't shorten a base64 string.

How to fix this one.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

try {

 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } else {
            Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show the whole code for the request?

Comment: By using PUT or POST instead of GET.

Comment: obviously HTTP GET is a bad choice for sending data to the server ... if you are using POST then pass the data as body of the request not as the url params ...

Answer (score 5):

Try Retrofit. Use  @FormUrlEncoded in retrofit and @POST("ur_api_name")
and send the data using @Field("data") annotation.

Comment: Thank you for this one. This can be used when @Query is having Http 414 URI too long exception

Answer (score 1):

### Using **POST** method instead of **GET** method in Client and Server side

> - In Android via **Retrofit** package

```
public interface TaskService {  

@FormUrlEncoded

@POST("tasks")

Call<String> createTask(@Field("title") String title);

}
```

> - In Service on Server for example **WCF Service**

```
[ServiceContract]

public interface IOperationService
{

[OperationContract]

[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "tasks", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]

string createTask();

}
```

> - then you must set **maxReceivedMessageSize** parameter in Web.config file in WCF Servic

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<webHttpBinding>
<binding name="myServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" maxBufferSize="10485760" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
<security mode="None"/>
</binding>
</webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, if this is true:

> I am trying to pull an base64 encoded image from my app to database(which is in my server), but I get this error.

you should change

```
Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
```

to

```
Log.d("JSON", "Failed to upload file");
```

Sending from your app to the database is uploading, not downloading.

Because you're uploading, you should **not** use a `HTTPGet` request, but a `HTTPPost` request. The difference is that GET is made for downloading, while POST is made for uploading. Therefore POST is allowed to have a body.

A body is the actual content of the message. Right now it seems like you're encoding the image in the request, which is not considered good practice. You already ran into the problems it creates. Because you're using a body you will have to change your server-side application.

For sending a body, take a look at [how to make httpPost call with json encoded body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533234/how-to-make-httppost-call-with-json-encoded-body). This question is specifically about using a JSON body, but you could use it anyways.