# How to upload image from gallery to sever in android without getting 414 error?

Tags: android, gallery

I am trying to upload image to server from gallery and camera. Image from camera is working fine. But when i tried to upload image from gallery, i got error message like "414 Request-URI Too Long, The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server." Here is my code and let me find a proper solution.

```
public class MyProfile extends BaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

@InjectView(R.id.visit_id)
TextView visitID;
@InjectView(R.id.name)
EditText name;
@InjectView(R.id.email)
EditText email;
@InjectView(R.id.mobile)
EditText mobile;
@InjectView(R.id.organization)
EditText organization;
@InjectView(R.id.designation)
EditText designation;
@InjectView(R.id.address_one)
EditText doorNo;
@InjectView(R.id.address_two)
EditText area;
@InjectView(R.id.address_three)
EditText city;
@InjectView(R.id.pincode)
EditText pincode;
@InjectView(R.id.web)
EditText website;
@InjectView(R.id.twitter_account)
EditText twitterAcc;
@InjectView(R.id.linkedin_account)
EditText linkedInAcc;
@InjectView(R.id.facebook_account)
EditText facebookAcc;
@InjectView(R.id.date_of_birth)
EditText dateOfBirth;
@InjectView(R.id.add_photo)
Button addPhoto;
@InjectView(R.id.add_edu_details)
Button educationDetails;
@InjectView(R.id.gender_spinner)
Spinner genderSpinner;
@InjectView(R.id.submit_button)
Button submitProfile;
@InjectView(R.id.profile_picture_vcard)
de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView profileImage;
@InjectView(R.id.date_picker_rl)
RelativeLayout datePickerLayout;
@InjectView(R.id.cal_img)
ImageView datePickerImg;

ViewProfileModel profileModel = new ViewProfileModel();
String myVisitID;
String gender;
View viewHolder;
Context context;
private Uri filePath;
ProgressDialog progress;
public static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CAMERA = 100;
public static int REQUEST_CAMERA = 200;
public static int SELECT_FILE = 300;
int year, month, day;
String photo;
String encoded;
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
public static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    viewHolder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, viewHolder);
    SvgUtility.setImageDrawable(getActivity(), R.raw.calender, datePickerImg);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CAMERA);
        }
    }

    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                getActivity(),
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add("Male");
    categories.add("Female");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    genderSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    myVisitID = bundle.getString("my_visit_id");
    visitID.setText(myVisitID);
    fnViewProfile();

    addPhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    educationDetails.setOnClickListener(this);
    submitProfile.setOnClickListener(this);
    genderSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    datePickerLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    gender = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add_photo:
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.DialogSlideAnim));
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_photo_editor);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            getActivity().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

            Button take_photo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.take_picture);
            Button from_gallery = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.choose_grom_gallery);
            Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

            take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                }
            });

            from_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
                }
            });

            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
            break;

        case R.id.add_edu_details:
            if (CommonUtils.checknetConnection(getActivity())) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EducationDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("my_visit_id", myVisitID);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                CommonUtils.ShowAlert(getActivity(), "Check interner connection");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.submit_button:
            if (CommonUtils.checknetConnection(getActivity())) {
                validateFields();
            } else {
                CommonUtils.ShowAlert(getActivity(), "Check interner connection");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.date_picker_rl:
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    dateOfBirth.setText(year + "-"
                            + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);

                }
            }, year, month, day);
            dpd.show();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    if (response == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        if (request == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 45, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

            profileImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        } else if (response == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (request == SELECT_FILE) {
            if (response == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data && data.getData() != null) {

                filePath = data.getData();
                Bitmap bm;

                try {

                    bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 45, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                    encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    profileImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void validateFields() {

    if (CommonUtils.isEmptyEdittext(name)) {
        name.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_fname));
        name.requestFocus();
    } else if (CommonUtils.isEmptyEdittext(email)) {
        email.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.enter_email));
        email.requestFocus();
    } else if (!CommonUtils.isEmailValid(email.getText().toString().trim())) {
        email.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_email));
        email.requestFocus();
    } else if (CommonUtils.isEmptyEdittext(mobile)) {
        mobile.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_mobile));
        mobile.requestFocus();
    } else if (!CommonUtils.isMobileNumber(mobile.getText().toString().trim())) {
        mobile.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_valid_mobile));
        mobile.requestFocus();
    } else if (CommonUtils.isEmptyEdittext(organization)) {
        organization.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_organization));
        organization.requestFocus();
    } else if (CommonUtils.isEmptyEdittext(designation)) {
        designation.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_designation));
        designation.requestFocus();
    } else if (CommonUtils.isEmptyEdittext(doorNo)) {
        doorNo.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_addr_1));
        doorNo.requestFocus();
    } else if (CommonUtils.isEmptyEdittext(area)) {
        area.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_addr_2));
        area.requestFocus();
    } else if (CommonUtils.isEmptyEdittext(city)) {
        city.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_addr_3));
        city.requestFocus();
    } else if (CommonUtils.isEmptyEdittext(pincode)) {
        pincode.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_area_code));
        pincode.requestFocus();
    } else if (CommonUtils.isEmptyEdittext(dateOfBirth)) {
        dateOfBirth.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.e_dob));
        dateOfBirth.requestFocus();
    } else {

        profileModel.setFirstName(name.getText().toString());
        profileModel.setDob(dateOfBirth.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setGender(gender);
        profileModel.setArea(area.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setPIN(pincode.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setDoorNo(doorNo.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setCity(city.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setDesignation(designation.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setOrganization(organization.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setEmail(email.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setMobile(mobile.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setFacebook_Link(facebookAcc.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setTwitter_Link(twitterAcc.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setLinkedln_Link(linkedInAcc.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setWebsite(website.getText().toString().trim());
        profileModel.setPhotopath(encoded);
        fnSubmitProfile(profileModel);
    }
}

void fnSubmitProfile(final ViewProfileModel value) {
    new BgAsyncTask<ViewProfileResult>(getActivity()) {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progress.setMessage("Submitting your details..");
            progress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Call<ViewProfileResult> onRun() {
            return apiService.submitProfile(myVisitID,
                    value.getEmail(), value.getFirstName(),
                    value.getMobile(), value.getOrganization(),
                    value.getDesignation(), value.getDoorNo(),
                    value.getCity(), value.getArea(),
                    value.getPIN(), value.getGender(),
                    value.getDob(), value.getWebsite(),
                    value.getFacebook_Link(), value.getTwitter_Link(),
                    value.getLinkedln_Link(), value.getPhotopath());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSuccess(Call<ViewProfileResult> result) {
            result.enqueue(new Callback<ViewProfileResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ViewProfileResult> call, Response<ViewProfileResult> response) {
                    if (progress.isShowing()) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                    if (response.body() != null && response.body().getResponseObject().equalsIgnoreCase("Profile Updated Successfully")) {
                        CommonUtils.showSnacbarToast(viewHolder, "Profile Updated Successfully");
                    } else {
                        CommonUtils.showSnacbarToast(viewHolder, "Profile update failed");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ViewProfileResult> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.v("onFailure", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onComplete() {
            super.onComplete();
        }
    }.execute();
}

private void fnViewProfile() {

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient(context).create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ViewProfileResult> call = apiService.viewProfile(myVisitID);

    progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progress.setMessage("Fetching your profile..");
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ViewProfileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ViewProfileResult> call, Response<ViewProfileResult> response) {

            if (progress.isShowing()) {
                progress.dismiss();
            }

            if (response.body().getProfiledata() != null && response.body().getProfiledata().size() > 0) {

                try {
                    loadDataToView(response.body().getProfiledata().get(0));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("", "No response: ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ViewProfileResult> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

private void loadDataToView(ViewProfileModel viewProfileModel) throws IOException {

    name.setText(viewProfileModel.getFirstName());
    email.setText(viewProfileModel.getEmail());
    mobile.setText(viewProfileModel.getMobile());
    dateOfBirth.setText(viewProfileModel.getDob());
    organization.setText(viewProfileModel.getOrganization());
    designation.setText(viewProfileModel.getDesignation());
    doorNo.setText(viewProfileModel.getDoorNo());
    area.setText(viewProfileModel.getArea());
    city.setText(viewProfileModel.getCity());
    pincode.setText(viewProfileModel.getPIN());
    website.setText(viewProfileModel.getWebsite());
    facebookAcc.setText(viewProfileModel.getFacebook_Link());
    twitterAcc.setText(viewProfileModel.getTwitter_Link());
    linkedInAcc.setText(viewProfileModel.getLinkedln_Link());

    photo = viewProfileModel.getPhotopath();
    URL url = new URL(photo);
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
    profileImage.setImageBitmap(image);

    String gender = viewProfileModel.getGender();
    if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Male")) {
        genderSpinner.setSelection(0);

    } else {
        genderSpinner.setSelection(1);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my error code:

09-15 14:14:42.552 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp: <-- 414 Request-URI Too Long http://example.com/Visit_Id=89&Email=bakya@tvs.com&FirstName=Bakyaraj&MobileNumber=8682976057&Organization=Tvs%20Infotech&Designation=Software%20engineer&DoorNo=4/316,%20Dhamalerimuthur&City=Vellore&Area=Tirupattur(Tk)&PIN=635853&Gender=Male&Dob=1990-09-19&Website=tvsnext.io&Facebook_Link=bakyaraj008@gmail.com&Twitter_Link=bakyaraj008&Linkedln_Link=bakya-raj&Photopath=/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABIMDRANCxIQDhAUExIVGywdGxgYGzYnKSAsQDlEQz85%0APj1HUGZXR0thTT0%2BWXlaYWltcnNyRVV9hnxvhWZwcm7/2wBDARMUFBsXGzQdHTRuST5Jbm5ubm5u%0Abm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm7/wAARCAKAAeADASIA%0AAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA%0AAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3%0AODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm%0Ap6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4%2BTl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3%2BPn6/8QAHwEA%0AAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx%0ABhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK%0AU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3%0AuLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3%2BPn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDuKKKK%0AACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA%0AKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAozSE8UxWy1AElFFFABRRSbhQAhUGkCCng%0A5ooAaEAoKinUGgCJlGKryBccirTMOlVJyBnnmpZSKkoxmq7NjoamkkzkHpVWV%2BoGMetIvc6Wiiir%0AMgooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKA%0ACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooARulRZFSMe1QMCCO1ICwvKijNMRuMUoWmA%0AZz0ppHNOxRs9aQAKcDSBaCMDvTAUsBUTPyRTWOD1qNmweaQ0K8n51TmfjJI5qWQ8ZzVKdqTKSIJp%0AMH%2BtQbgelOk%2BbvUYBHUd6RR19FFFWZBRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFF%0AFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQBF0b8%0AaJFzggZp7LnnvSMcL0pACDin0yPkZp9MAooooAKCM0UUARsgxUTxZFWabtpAZ8kROapzRcd8VrNF%0AVeSH8RUtFpmMYyP4cUkqYHSr7xAdOlRMvykHikUmdBRRRWhkFFFBOBQAUU0NnoKcOaACiiigAooo%0AoAKKKKACignFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFF%0AFABRRQDmgAooooAKKKKACiiigAprKCCKdRQAiDC4paaG%2BcrinUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAJtqNkyDUt%0AIaQFG4jA7fSqE4GMEYNadz6VnSjrU2LRuUUUVZAUHpRSDk5zxQAirgU6iigAooooAKKKKACkY4pa%0AKAGgZHNOooIzQAUUAYooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACi%0AiigAoxzRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUANwd%2BfalY4GaU8Uh6GgAByM0tMi6Gn0AFFFFABRRRQAUh%0AGaWg0AVpos85qm0WM9KvyKTx0qAj6VJSZdpMgUzPPNKxG2mSBOeM08DFRIfU9KkByM0ALRRmimAU%0AH2pCwBA9aWgAooooAKKaWxk44oRsigB1FNZ8dOTTh05oAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAoooo%0AAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigBGGVNRPuHfipqjJzk%0AenFIBYgQnPWn0gGBilpgFFFFABRRRQAU1zgUM4Xqap3N2M4WgCSZ/lyG4qpJOV6Zx7VG90MEE/l2%0AqtNJnkHt3pXKSN9lzSAH0p%2B2kIwpoJGIvBJPWjcAcE4piEsuT3pJGxQBMrDbkmhJN2fQVXEmRtFP%0AAwMCgBrSEuD0xU0bl%2B3FV2JL4HAqVH24Gcn2pgT0UDpzRQAyU4U1HnsKdK4xikQgBicUgEQEnoam%0AUY702L7tPpgFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFU7zU7WxUmeZVwM46mi1xFyiuWuvHNp%0AGQba3nmQ9W24/nWVqPjK9vEaK0h%2BzIerty2PanbuNXZ28l7bRHDzxqfQtVJ/EOnxuVeXAH8WOK4r%0A7crgeau6Qfxmrdlr/wBjG2S1jmj6HjkU7Iaizs4NTs7gAxXMTZ/2qtAg9DXGHxFpE%2BPOsHjGfvrH%0AjBq6k6g%2BbpeobyR/qpXyP8aViTp6KwbbxH5TpFqUXks3R1ztP%2BFbkciyIHRgynkEd6TVguOooooG%0AFFJuGcUvSgAopOopaACiiigAooooAKKKKACq4y0xGeM1Y7VA%2BY5VbseKQE9FFFMAopAwJwDS0AFI%0AxwpPpS1UuLzy2KgDjvQBXmmbf171BOQfmVgeOlRXFx5jE4xVKSQ/3uallJD5H2k4/KoTJ2pryDrn%0AINRk8fWpRR2QPI5pJm2xmoS5VetRy3JI2461ZmSB8YQdaVwD71BvJYEk5qeBfl3PmgBm3ackcmnh%0A8Dk06UbhkVXKk5x0oAfkEk1JGMNuIJPaq6vg4NW4DlaAJaCcdaKZL2pgV5T89I7ninXBHmDHTuai%0AOWPsKQEsUxHXpVlWDDiq6AADNTBugHSgB9FFFMAooooAKKKKACiiigAooqhqGs2WngiedFf%2B7nmh%0AK4i8WCjJIA9TWbquu2umRb3JkJ6BOc1x%2BreIJ9UdkKtHbqeArfe%2BtZTOzcFmwOgJ6VVktxqLZ0l3%0A4uupW/0aJUAB%2B9nmsO4uZrqcy3LhjjG0DgVB5h9aaXNLmZooJErHaOKZnim7higSDp1qR7Ds5FNy%0Ac0bhSbgaBjs5GDyKdbkRNlRsJ/iXg0wUhagRoS6m8oVJgHRSOTySK6DRtZitotoZjFngHt9K47di%0ApI53RdqsQvpVJkSjc9K/t
09-15 14:14:42.552 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp: CJojIrgY7E0R6jHJEWX5iPTvXn6X0g6OQO4qzBfm2DbZpCeo9CaehPK%0Azr7jVoYk8xX2hfvK3GKs/aklVHRwVIz1rhZ9WkuUw8S46Ejqafpetf2fMsciloWYAMT92hJPQTTW%0Ap3scmcCpVBGazIrkvtkQfKe1XorlJG2j72M1NgJqKKKBhRRRQAUUUUAFVrxiijjIzVmobtN8Jx25%0ApAQicsBn0pfP2nGeaqlmC528g05QWO7%2BdFwsTxSkSkkcdKmmnEagjBJrOluwgKjJPqKgln3IPnOe%0A9FwsaUl6ojOR%2BXasq6l3Hg5HXrVaSRsH5jULSZ60m0Ul3HtJx7VAz0rMccVEep560ihSR%2BNMLfjQ%0ATjrUbtyOaEM7WSPDH0qCRcgY49avSKGQiqUzHbyMVRkKiAyYHbrVtdoXHeq8cZRNzcH1pyE7iQOl%0ACBjpBxk/pVdn2vgVPkMO9QSIN5zzQAwEl%2BmKvw/cFZ6ZDEYq9A3GM5oAlqNxubBOPSpOgqrNMKYE%0ATDMuOvNSuRgEAZquZSZSfyqeM7iO/tSASNcnnPvVpFA6VGEEfLHrTfM2vkEYoAsUUituFG7Bxjim%0AAtFFFABRRRQAUySRIkLyOqKOpY4AptzKIYHkLKu0ZyxwBXB6s0muyBt0qQjqXOASPagNzX1rxjax%0AE21g5mkPWRPuj8a5GUebK0kh3ljn5ualMMduCqYAHpULPRctRFLUwmml6aWpFjyaaTTd1GaBgWpA%0A3NKVOM0zGKBEi5FPGAMmmJT6AJNo2896jNOL/KRUW7mgQ40inBpxIIpvFAIkByKcrkDHaoAxzUqs%0ACDnrQGxMk2BgY/GmTASLgjio84o3UgNLS9XubYCJpMx9u%2BK2dO1h5tSSPzAFPXHcVygfByDWhbsD%0AEsqHbMDxirTIlHselKwZQR0NLWVoOoC8tFyQXHWtXpSasQFFFFAwooooAKQjII9aWigCjGAzMvcH%0AFJPHsQgZB7Gn3SiGVZhwCcMKkmYGHcMc9M1LWgIw5socVEcDkmn3T5dgR0NVy%2BARSKB%2BMionNOZ%2B%0A3U1G/HpmlYoaT3prZzS57frUbHnrTEKMZ5pjDilBzSMaQ0ztw%2BATnioXOUJNLvC5GDzSTH92easz%0AJcebtAPA71L5Y24FR2o%2BSpsgHFAFWcbPeqzyENkVeuApAzVIorScdKACMkMM96swEKxz3piKGPAp%0AXHloT1oAkmlKtgVVd8/MwP4U93MgBbtTSQSOce1MBiRMQWINTw5znGKa0gHAztoDELkGkBMXAc7j%0AzSohbpjFQQrvO6Q4Aq3EQQdowKAHjpS01lz3IpIwNvFMBwJz0paO1ANABRnAJNFISACT0oAwNVka%0A7iZrgPDAv3EPBb3Yfyrk7q7Mn7tHPkqeMd60vFmvx3UZtLNy0m7Ehxwo9M1gPMSANoGKb2sVBdRH%0AOe/SmE0jE0wmpNRSc0hNIDSGmgsG6gHmkxShaVx2J1IZKYy4NEeVp55FFybWGilpAOaWgBJDio8n%0ANPbmk20XHYTNKtNYYpy0CHYoDYNHamnrSAcWpCabmkBp2EPBqxbvkhCcBuM1VBp4Pp17UCNy3urn%0ARpYpwmYeF47iu7tHM0CSlg24Ajb0rzn%2B05byxe0mVcAcH1rpvBupGe1FtKTvQYGe9XbQzaszpxRS%0AbhnGeaWpATPOKSTIQkdQMikZgBkdqHb90T1OKQCRSq6A5AOORT8j1rEG6VWJJwrdM1IodIDJubOO%0A5ouFi5qEieSUzzjgVSbUo3tVRhhh0qjNMxxlic9qqMQG460rodiSd8k81AX5OaQ5Ax2FNZs0ihS2%0AOODmmjkYFMLc8fhRkigYpamnmkzSE9qdgQtDdKaW9KUnI70gOvfKtn3psp2r65qxIvHAxUUsXyZb%0Ag1RmEM5Vfl5pWuST2/Co48eXnHPtUPzbuTxQBPJMMeuaYUYDOcE1EzYIFTKxcgnPFAyzECijPX%2Bd%0AEwYj5ep7U9Y2kXLED6VIke0cncfU0CKvkbEAzmoXOWOBwK0CUCnGBUCR/uWJABNAFPBY809Iyx9P%0ApU1tFk%2Bo9akQbWIwc%2BtADooFA5z%2BdTgYGBVeN3DEbalEg78GgB5oAwKKKYBRRRQAVyXjDxIbUCy0%0A%2BQGdvvsP4BVzxhqpsbAwxTeU8gPzA/N%2BFcFAmzLMcu3JJ609tRqPMOUeVHtzknkn1NMLUOcmmE1J%0AqlYGYmm8mgdaei5pNlJCBadsp4XFPC5oBEYTNPEVTKntUnl8VNyisUwKbirJjqJlwaaE0RnimMad%0AKecDrUeeaaJZIozTwvFEYyBTyMCkxkDrmkHFSNTKEDEoxRTgOKYiNqj71I4pmOaYhc08NUZ60A0C%0AJVcg5FXdJ1GWzukdB8oOcA1nZqSGQKwz0pp2E1c9BbxFBJGCquHAzjFaVvqME0IYSLuxyM1xloAY%0A1zyD39at29mksoBOxj3pXRnynS/aVZmwwK1LnfBhTya52WymtiNkrEHpj1p8N1qFsN2FdR14ouh2%0AZZQul20bNjPWp5WIyhbK9uaymvnklMjL8x64qaG/iETJJneTxmkgYyYcnA4Heq7HHbipGnTzOGJU%0A%2BtMlwAeeKmzGRE5qNjgn0oY5NIx5qhjSaTNBNJmgB1MPFODDHPNRmkCFY05eRzUfWlB4xQCPQdg7%0A81FcjMR7Gp6o3rFQQufzqyCC1c8g0yZ852mo4wC3sKfGoYkntUjGxR7yB3PWtPytqgKOarWkD5JG%0AOvU1oAY9zQkIRBhcGhgx4GMU4nFQPPtYDpVAEoCrzyT0qQrhQAOlRI4eVR%2BlWKQEMRCKQAc05dpX%0A0zTNxMhUDGalYAJxQA3BXtTChMgLcDrimB8PyxPtR998jOKAJ/MWl3Z%2B7TNofgcYqRQFGBQAo6c0%0AUhYKMk4FRCVn3bRgAcGmB5/42mW48QBFYt5KYYdlNY5apLyQvqV47EljKRk9eMioM05bmkNgY00m%0AgmkqSxVGTVmJKgjHNW4RUspCOmMGiPGambBGKrtlDQtdBFpTgUueKgjlBHJqTdStYd7imq8zYapW%0AlAFVZWLNTSAafmyajPWrCrhahK5bFNBYmgbjBp7NUYTHIpetIQx2pVGRSEZbFPAoENI5pwHFDDAp%0A6dKBkciZHFQVbYVWYYJpoCM80dKDRTJAGl5wQPSkFFAjrPD4F/pI%2BX95CdtPyScNww71X8GybYH2%0AEn5sOPStbVLcYE0Yx6gDrSlvchPoVvtMrxFGckjpWtb/ADWoGCRj86w4mzKueOeR6Vu2Vyv%2BrH8I%0Ap7oTVmVNOjVb2UOnBOPpVnUNMhI3KOT3xVa3lKX0oOBnn8auXM5ZMZ59RSewJ6mFJbbGKjp/KopF%0AZDjJxVxiRIcnOe/rVafBk4zipKRAScZpC3NSsQBgdu9I0eBuyAO9MaIi1ITSuAT8oxUZoAd34pGp%0AM0mfxoAXNANJmkB70AejHH41UvVXb856irlZ97GWuY13fLzxVGZUjhYjPardnGDkYwR3NWZIgI8L%0A0xUNqCWYUrAWY%2BCRUlVg4ikw3OfSnmcc89KoCR2CjnpVSc/MN3TtTLmVmP8As1A828AN1FAi3bH9%0A8fpVysy0ZmkPIwKuPOqxnk5ApIZE02Ziew6Uq3GeWGSO1U/NxuNNjl2sSaBFuMGSTJ4zUy7UbB61%0AVNx0xxSiXPQc0AXPMVFzg1B9oIlHp6VG0xxjGaiLOWDYoAvykMFBU4NOQCNTxVKOZi2N2asCVmQq%0AeuOKBnlt%2B2/Vr1l4Uyn%2BZqE8Cr2oWEllfTJOCZGctn1BOapyDFN73NI7ERoAyaDSp1qWWTRr0q1G%0AvFQwLk1cSM1JSGbc0x4tw

```
09-15 14:14:42.553 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    Date:Thu,15 Sep 2016 08:44:01 
09-15 14:14:42.553 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    Server:Apache
09-15 14:14:42.553 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    Content-Length: 248
09-15 14:14:42.553 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    Connection: close
09-15 14:14:42.553 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
09-15 14:14:42.573 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
09-15 14:14:42.573 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    <html>    <head>
09-15 14:14:42.573 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    <title>414 Request-URI Too Long</title>
09-15 14:14:42.574 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    </head>    <body>
09-15 14:14:42.574 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    <h1>Request-URI Too Long    </h1>
09-15 14:14:42.574 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    <p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
09-15 14:14:42.574 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    limit for this server.<br />
09-15 14:14:42.574 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    </p>
09-15 14:14:42.574 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:    </body>    </html>
09-15 14:14:42.574 18703-19101/com.ecard D/OkHttp:<-- END HTTP (248-byte body)
```

Comment: post your code of image upload

Comment: updated. Is that you want?

Comment: no http connection code where actual upload of image is happening

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533234/how-to-make-httppost-call-with-json-encoded-body this link will help you

Comment: updated the code. I receive photopath as string from url